# How to make multiple jquery table which are refreshing itself in single HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making admin portal, where admin can see the total number of current booking, for this we have to refresh table every 10 sec automatically and there will be also refresh button, which also refresh the table, I am using the JQuery, Ajax, Json, Spring MVC, **I am trying to make more than one Jquery table which are refreshing theirself every 10 seconds**, **But only one table is refreshing, other is not.** , Thanks in advance for help and any suggestion,

[image]

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Service for home - New Page -  Next Generation of Service Provider - Admin Home Page</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="assets/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="vendors/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="vendors/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            function fetchData(){
                $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
                $.get("http://localhost:8080/HotelServiceProvider/getAllHotelBookingDetails", function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, contact) {
                        $(".data-contacts1-js").append(
                            "<tr><td>" + contact.custId + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custMobile + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custEmail + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custAddress + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.Date + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.Time + "</td></tr>"
                            );
                    });
                });
            }          
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty(); 
                setInterval(function(){
                    fetchData();
                },10000);  // this will call your fetchData function for every 5 Sec.
            });

             $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".data-contacts1-js tbody").empty();
                $('#fetchContacts1').click(function() {
                     fetchData();
                });
            });

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            function fetchData(){
                $(".data-contacts2-js tbody").empty();
                $.get("http://localhost:8080/PGServiceProvider/getAllPgBookingDetails", function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, contact) {
                        $(".data-contacts2-js").append(
                            "<tr><td>" + contact.custId + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custMobile + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custEmail + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.custAddress + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.Date + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + contact.Time + "</td></tr>"
                            );
                    });
                });
            }          
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".data-contacts2-js tbody").empty(); 
                setInterval(function(){
                    fetchData();
                },10000);  // this will call your fetchData function for every 5 Sec.
            });

             $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".data-contacts2-js tbody").empty();
                $('#fetchContacts2').click(function() {
                     fetchData();
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">         
                <!--/span-->
                <div class="span9" id="content">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <!-- block -->
                        <div class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div class="muted pull-left">Carpenter Services</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content collapse in">
                                <div class="span12">
                                     <table class="data-contacts1-js table table-striped" >
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <th>ID</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Mobile</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Email</th>
                                                  <th>Address</th>
                                                  <th>Date</th>
                                                  <th>Time</th>
                                                  <th>Status</th>
                                            </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                      <tbody>

                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>                                    
                                </div>
                                <button id="fetchContacts1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Refresh</button>                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /block -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <!-- block -->
                        <div class="block">
                            <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                                <div class="muted pull-left">Carpenter Services</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content collapse in">
                                <div class="span12">
                                    <table class="data-contacts2-js table table-striped" >
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <th>ID</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Name</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Mobile</th>
                                                  <th>Customer Email</th>
                                                  <th>Address</th>
                                                  <th>Date</th>
                                                  <th>Time</th>
                                                  <th>Status</th>
                                            </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                      <tbody>

                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>                                    
                                </div>
                                <button id="fetchContacts2" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Refresh</button>                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /block -->
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>         

        </div>
        <!--/.fluid-container-->

        <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {

        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have great success with this,  http://www.datatables.net/ -  it's open source and I am not affiliated with them in any way so I dont think this is spam.

Comment: @Satpal, hi Satpal, As I see you make this question duplicate, It is right both question is posted by me but both question is different, In first question is about refreshing of single table, Now that problem is solved, This question is about refreshing of two table in single HTML page, My problem is that only single table is refreshing, So I am requesting you to  please review again your decision and make it Unique question means Not duplicate, Thanks . Any suggestions are welcome, waiting for your reply. Thanks...

Comment: I closed the question as it was having almost same title and content now reopened.

Comment: @Satpal, Thank-you very much  Satpal, Inn future I will keep in mind these things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `fetchData` twice. Because you call the functions in your callback it does not matter that those functions are defined in two different `script` tags.

Both `fetchData` are defined in the global scope, and the second one *overwrites* the first one. Thats why `.data-contacts2-js` is only update.

This example shows the different behaviors when functions a looked up.

```
<!-- script block 1 -->
<script>
  setTimeout(test,100);//will call test #1 
  setTimeout(function() {
    test();//will call test #2
  },100);

  //test #1
  function test() {
     console.log(1);
  }
</script>

<!-- script block 2 -->
<script>
  setTimeout(test,100); //will call test #2
  setTimeout(function() {
    test(); //will call test #2
  },100);

  //test #2
  function test() {
    console.log(2);
  }
</script>
```

First the *script block 1* is evaluated, because of that  `setTimeout(test,100);` refers to the `test #1` function.

Then the second script block is evaluated, before it is executed the `test #2` is already known and because of that the `setTimeout(test,100);`   in the second script block refers to `test #2`.

When the cllback for both `setTimeout(function() {test();},100);` executed after `100ms` the `test()` inside this callback will call `test #2` for both script blocks, as `test #2` is *shadowing* `test #1`